# How does the Arcane Archer fighter's Piercing Arrow interact with magical ammunition such as +3 arrows?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, fighter, ammunition, arcane-archer

A [*+3 arrow*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/arrows-3) loses its magical property once it hits a target, but the description on the [Arcane Archer fighter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#ArcaneArcher)'s Piercing Arrow (XGtE, p. 29) says that the target takes damage **as if** it was hit by the arrow.

Does that mean that if an Arcane Archer uses Piercing Arrow with a *+3 arrow* and hits multiple targets with it, the arrow doesn't stop being +3 after the first target?

And if it doesn't lose its magic, is it the same with [*arrows of slaying*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/arrow-of-slaying)?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 10):

## All creatures take the same [base] damage

5th Edition D&D doesn't stipulate that there's an "order" to which creatures get hit first by Area-of-Effect effects, and the effect of the *Piercing Arrow* Shot is to turn an arrow into an area-of-effect.

> **Piercing Arrow.** You use transmutation magic to give your arrow an ethereal quality. When you use this option, you don't make an attack roll for the attack. Instead, the arrow shoots forward in a line, which is 1 foot wide and 30 feet long, before disappearing. The arrow passes harmlessly through objects, ignoring cover. Each creature in that line must make a Dexterity saving throw. On a failed save, a creature takes damage as if it were hit by the arrow, plus an extra 1d6 piercing damage. On a successful save, a target takes half as much damage.
>   The piercing damage increases to 2d6 when you reach 18th level in this class.
>
> —**Arcane Archer**, Xanathar's Guide to Everything, pg. 29

So while some DMs might interpret this to logically mean "it hits the first target in the line, then the creature behind them, then the creature behind them, ...", the rules don't expressly say that this is how it is meant to work, and in most other terms (things like Saving Throws, etc.) the damage is occurring simultaneously against all targets.

So by my reading of the rules [and their absence of any clarifying information in relation to this question], if the damage occurs simultaneously for all creatures, then that also means the arrow must "hit" all creatures simultaneously as well. So because no one creature is hit before any other, all of them must take the bonus damage associated with the arrow, if it applies to them (like in the *Arrow of Slaying* example).

Comment: Actually, the arrow doesn't "hit" any of the creatures per the description, it just deals damage _as if_ it hit the creatures. So RAW it's kind of questionable if the +3 or slaying arrow loses its magic at all (aside from the fact that the arrow disappears in the end anyway).

Comment: @Cubic Well, "as-if it hit" has to imply, mechanically, that all effects triggered by a creature being hit by the arrow have to go off. It has to be symmetrical in that regard: we can't choose to be hit by the extra damage on the arrow but then insist that the "this arrow becomes normal once it hits something" part doesn't apply.

Comment: the reason I pointed it out was because the magic arrow descriptions all say their activate their effects if a creature takes damage from the arrow, not when they hit a target.

Comment: @Cubic I think you'll find that that very much depends on the specific arrow, actually. For example, +3 Ammunition definitely says "when the arrow hits a target", not "when the arrow deals damage". The wording is not perfectly consistent from item to item.

Comment: The special effect of an arrow+3 is the +hit and +damage, it doesn't 'activate' at all. It loses its effect on hit, *not* when it deals damage, slaying arrows are worded the same way - they lose their magic on hit, but their effect activates upon dealing damage.

Comment: @Cubic Do you have a reliable source in front of you? Mine definitely does not have them worded the same: mine reads "*Once an arrow of slaying deals its extra damage to a creature, it becomes a nonmagical arrow.*" (**Arrow of Slaying**, DMG 152) and "*Once it hits a target, the ammunition is no longer magical.*" (**Ammunition +3**, DMG 150). The former does not mention hitting a target, it only mentions dealing damage; the latter does not mention dealing damage, only hitting a target.

Comment: It seems kinda weird saying that all damage happens at the same time, since an arrow clearly has a travel time no?

Comment: @RapidRabid Narratively, sure—but mechanically, it's not possible to sequence events in-between the damage taken by a creature in front and a creature in back. So as far as the game is concerned, those two damage sources must be simultaneous.